# how can i make a python script that uses windows's way of copying to copy files?

Tags: python, windows, automation, file-copying

I have a python program that I use to manage my files(because I have multiple USB hard disks). I want to add a copy feature to that program that allows me to use the Window's copy method to do it with the normal window that appears that allows resuming and pausing. is that possible?

Comment: [IFileOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation).

Comment: Example. Create the instance: `import pythoncom; from win32com.shell import shell;` `fo = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(shell.CLSID_FileOperation, None, pythoncom.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, shell.IID_IFileOperation)`. Create the source file and destination directory items: `src = shell.SHCreateItemFromParsingName(srcpath, None, shell.IID_IShellItem);` `dst = shell.SHCreateItemFromParsingName(dstpath, None, shell.IID_IShellItem)`. Queue and perform a copy operation: `fo.CopyItem(src, dst, None, None);` `fo.PerformOperations()`.

Comment: The default progress dialog only shows for long-running operations such as copying a very large file or many files.

Comment: Did the example code help you?